# How does OpenID Connect work?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Can someone shed some light on the use case for me.  We wave users who will be signing in to third party client applications.  Using OAUTH2 framework, the client app will redirect to our site to authenticate.  From my undestanding, the Authorization server will return a access token and an id_token (OpenID Connect).

1) If the user is authenticated with us and is redirected to the client application, if they leave the client application and go back into the client application hours later, do they still have go through the whole redirect to our /authorization endpoint to re-authenticate?

2) If the user is authenticated with us and is redirected to the client application, if they leave the client application and go to our site, do they have to login again to authenticate?

Basically, does OpenID Connect over OAUTH2 allow a user to sign in once and then not have to sign in again after subsequent visit to the third party app or our app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on two things:

   a. if the client application maintains a session and that session has not expired yet, the user won't be redirected at all

   b. in case the client session timed out, the user will be redirected but if the IDP still has an authentication session running, the user will not have to authenticate and will be sent back immediately to the client app with a new token.
2. It depends on the IDP session existence/timeout again

Essentially an Identity Provider authenticates users and decides how to do that. It can prompt for credentials but can also create and maintain authentication sessions for the user for (typically) a limited period of time which allows for true Single Sign On (SSO).

Also note that this behaviour does not depend on the exact protocol at hand (OpenID Connect, OAuth or even SAML): it would work the same for any protocol that redirects a user to an Identity Provider in a federated SSO system.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenID Connect, the session at RP typically starts when the RP validates  End-User's ID Token. ID token consists of expiration time. So if the user just leaves (not logged out) and the id_token is expired when he access the RP, then the end-user needs to re-authenticate.

If the end-user logged out from the relying party and the OpenID provider supported logout mechanisms such as OIDC session management, OIDC front-channel logout or OIDC back-channel logout, then all RPs sharing the same browser session will be logged out (SLO). Then the end-user needs to login to the OP again to access the RPs.